# modifySql append tag not working liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

trying to add partition to table in liquibase. modifysql append tag not working. Do we need to add any extra to append tag. below is the liquibase.xml

```
<changeSet author="server" id="1">
      <createTable tableName="USER_AUTHORITIES">
        <column autoIncrement="true" name="SEQUENCE_NO" type="INTEGER">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"
                primaryKeyName="USER_AUTHORITIESPK" />
        </column>
        <column name="LAST_MODIFIED_BY" type="VARCHAR(15)" />
        <column name="LAST_MODIFIED_DATE"
            type="TIMESTAMP with time zone not null" />
        <column name="APPLICATION" type="VARCHAR(15)" />
        <column name="CCG_ID" type="VARCHAR(10)" />
        <column name="PERMISSION" type="VARCHAR(15)" />
        <column name="PRIMARY_RESTRICTION" type="VARCHAR(15)" />
        <column name="SECONDARY_RESTRICTION" type="VARCHAR(15)" />
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="server" id="2">
    <modifyDataType schemaName="users"
        tableName="USER_AUTHORITIES" columnName="PERMISSION"
        newDataType="VARCHAR(50)" />
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="server" id="3">
    <modifyDataType schemaName="users"
        tableName="USER_AUTHORITIES" columnName="SEQUENCE_NO"
        newDataType="BIGINT" />
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="server" id="4">

    <modifySql dbms="postgresql">
        <append
            value="PARTITION BY RANGE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_MODIFIED_DATE)) (
      PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-04-01 00:00:00'))" />
    </modifySql>
   </changeSet>
  </databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the error you are getting? Also, what commands are you running to get the result?